# Why is my Rocksmith score going down?

Tags: rocksmith

Noticed a couple of days ago the big arrow that shows your score escalation was actually going from the top to the bottom. I wondered if maybe the game maxed out at it's max score so I started watching my score. I swear yesterday it was 65 million, but today it's down to 61 million. What gives?

**Update:**

Now it's down to 59 million. Strange, it doesn't seem to go down after an event, but rather after I qualify for an event or rehearse / riff repeat a song.

**Update:**

Now down to 55 million.

**Update**

Now down to 40 million.

**Update**

Now down to 30 million.

Comment: Do you play both guitar and bass? There's [a bug that may be effecting you](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/757742-Bug-Rocksmith-score-overflow-Forums), if so.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie you rule. I never thought to add my bass and guitar scores together. When I do, G30,255,430 + B69,744,570 sure enough it equals 1 billion combined rocksmith points exactly. Please add this as an answer, I'd be happy to give you the accept and close this answer out once and for all.

Comment: Glad to help! Good on you for persisting with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is [a bug that caps your combined guitar and bass scores at 1 billion](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/757742-Bug-Rocksmith-score-overflow-Forums). Each will increase just fine until they sum to 1,000,000,000, at which point increasing one subtracts from the other. By reports, it sounds like the bass score won't decrease, only the guitar score.

Comment: "By reports, it sounds like the bass score won't decrease, only the guitar score." I can confirm this report. My guitar score never increases, only my bass score, and when it does, the guitar score decreases.

Comment: Because no one could be that much of a rock god on both guitar and bass!